# Workbox ServiceWorker skip strategy interception

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I have a WebApp that uses a Workbox powered service worker to handle routes. Using a stale-while-revalidate strategy, let's say it intercepts calls from my app to `/api/abc`, returning the cached version when available, fetching the latest copy, then in the background messaging the app (via broadcast plugin) that a new version of the response is available.

From the apps perspective, the API call can return with stale data. And this is OK.

However, in one use case I want to skip this strategy, and really go to network, skipping the cache.

How can I get my app to make a fetch request that will be ignored by the service workers stale-while-revalidate strategy.

It's a "hard refresh" button, I want to give the user the chance to get the latest data, even if that is an error.  Otherwise, the user just hits refresh, and if the server is down or offline, the refresh call appears to complete, and a broadcast update never arrives.